# Can you do AVL/BST tree deletion this way?

Tags: algorithm

This question [was asked previously over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146048/deletion-a-node-from-binary-search-tree-with-2-nodes-with-a-different-method-po?rq=2).
The normal procedure for deletion is to take the in-order predecessor or successor and delete that. Can it also be done this way?

1. When the node is found, swap its value with the value of the child node to the left.
2. Recursively delete the left node.
3. If there is no left node, cut off the node and replace it with the right node at that point.

Essentially the node to be deleted gets swapped with the child node to the left, continuously, till there is no left node. At that point, it is cut off and the left node of the parent becomes the right node of the node that is cut off. This avoids the need to find the in-order successor/predecessor and change the value to be deleted.

Suppose we want to delete node 50 in an AVL or BST.

[image: New method]

Comment: Now do the next one.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError What do you mean next one?

Comment: I mean, with your scheme, what now happens when you delete 25?

Comment: the BST after the deletion you've provided as an example is not valid because 15 is on the left side of the 10, also 40, 30, 45 are on the left side of the 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot do it that way.

When you swap a node with its left child, and that left child has a right child, you'll introduce a BST violation that is not resolved by the continuation of the suggested algorithm. In your example, when 50 swaps to the top, it immediately puts all the nodes in subtree 40 (i.e. nodes 30, 40 and 45) in BST-violation.